# Modified Chassis Ground symbol?

Tags: analog, schematics

Is there a standard definition of the pictured ground symbol? It is distinct from an unmodified (without the rectangular box) symbol used in the same schematic.

Origin is USA, probably at least 10-20 years old, aerospace.

[image]

Comment: @hypfco Sorry, no, that's quite impossible. I do have a guess as to the meaning.

Comment: Never seen that one...what was your guess as to its meaning?

Comment: @TonyM Internal shield.

Comment: This could be used to denote dedicated EMI chassis connection. I sometimes draw my circuit-sketches (for presentations/reports) using a thicker horizontal bar to visually stress the significance of that bonding point

Comment: I have seen that symbol, but I can't remember the application. My guess is it implies a conducting enclosure like the skin of an aircraft or a cable shield or Faraday cage. Is there anything in the schematic that might give a clue?